# Highlight And UnderLine text in different colors - TextField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield, texteditingcontroller

How to create underlines for parts of text in textfield using offset , i can replace the mistake word with correct word but i can't change style of this is word to notify user that it's error.

I Can use the buildTextSpan Method but it's not working with me.

[image: Code of replacement]

[image: the result which i want to get]

Comment: What's not working in your `buildTextSpan` method? How did you implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to use a custom `TextEditingController` that overrides the `buildTextSpan` method. You can then return your own `TextSpan` that uses different styles for parts of the text.

Here's just a minimal example of how you can achieve that. Be aware that there might be some other aspects from the original `buildTextSpan` that you need to implement in the overriding method as well.

```dart
class HighlightRange {
  final int start;
  final int end;
  final Color color;

  HighlightRange({required this.start, required this.end, required this.color});
}

class CustomTextEditingController extends TextEditingController {
  // Hardcoded example; in real usage you should initialize it with
  // empty list and set the list through the controller instance
  List<HighlightRange> ranges = [
    HighlightRange(start: 11, end: 18, color: Colors.orange),
    HighlightRange(start: 31, end: 42, color: Colors.green),
  ];

  TextStyle _getHighlightStyle(HighlightRange range) {
    return TextStyle(
      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
      decorationColor: range.color,
    );
  }

  @override
  TextSpan buildTextSpan({
    required BuildContext context,
    TextStyle? style,
    required bool withComposing,
  }) {
    List<InlineSpan> children;

    if (ranges.isEmpty) {
      children = [TextSpan(text: text)];
    } else {
      children = [
        TextSpan(text: text.substring(0, ranges.first.start)),
        TextSpan(
          text: text.substring(ranges.first.start, ranges.first.end),
          style: _getHighlightStyle(ranges.first),
        ),
      ];

      for (int i = 1; i < ranges.length; i++) {
        children.addAll([
          TextSpan(text: text.substring(ranges[i - 1].end, ranges[i].start)),
          TextSpan(
            text: text.substring(ranges[i].start, ranges[i].end),
            style: _getHighlightStyle(ranges[i]),
          ),
        ]);
      }

      children.add(TextSpan(text: text.substring(ranges.last.end)));
    }

    return TextSpan(
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      children: children,
    );
  }
}
```

Define the controller with the custom controller class in the state of your `StatefulWidget`:

```dart
final controller = CustomTextEditingController();
```

You can access the `ranges` property:

```dart
controller.ranges = // Do something with it
```

[image: Result]